# Wordpress get post by tag name

Tags: wordpress

I want to query posts by tag `name` and not by tag `slug`

I've tried this but it will only work with tag `slug`

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => "news_type", 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'tag' => "my tag" );
```

An alternative would be to get a tag by the tag name, and then get slug from the tag.

( I only have access to the tag name in my code)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best way to achieve this is with a [`tax_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters). You can either pass the `term_id` (which is the default), `name` or `slug` to the `terms` parameter

You can try something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news_type',
     'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => 'NAME OF THE TAG',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```